# qmail-inject returns 111

Tags: c++, c, linux, qmail

Hi i got a problem with qmail. I want to send an email from my program i got 111 error code from qmail-inject. But if i try to send same email from command line it works.

In my code :

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        logger.error("error creating on new process");
}

else if (pid == 0) {
      logger.info("qmail-inject is calling now for Dlp Notify");
      if (execl("/opt/program/bin/sendmail","sendmail", notifySender, tempMail,(char*)   0) == -1)  {
        logger.error("notify operation failed: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

sendmail is a script just like that :

```
/bin/cat $2 | /opt/smtp/bin/qmail-inject -f   $1
```

when i run this script on command line that works well. But from my program that doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possibly some other qmail related binary is crashing.
Please run a strace on the process and check what is crashing. If possible share the info with us, we can possibly help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your C code to execute `qmail-inject` looks ok, at least from what you show us.

`man qmail-inject` [tells us exit code 111 indicates a temporary error](http://qmail.org/man/man8/qmail-inject.html).

`qmail-inject`'s sources (v1.03, which look the same here for netqmail 1.06) show the following:

```
void temp() { _exit(111); }
void die_nomem() {
 substdio_putsflush(subfderr,"qmail-inject: fatal: out of memory\n"); temp(); }
void die_invalid(sa) stralloc *sa; {
 substdio_putsflush(subfderr,"qmail-inject: fatal: invalid header field: ");
 substdio_putflush(subfderr,sa->s,sa->len); perm(); }
void die_qqt() {
 substdio_putsflush(subfderr,"qmail-inject: fatal: unable to run qmail-queue\n"); temp(); }
void die_chdir() {
 substdio_putsflush(subfderr,"qmail-inject: fatal: internal bug\n"); temp(); }
void die_read() {
 if (errno == error_nomem) die_nomem();
 substdio_putsflush(subfderr,"qmail-inject: fatal: read error\n"); temp(); }
```

From the latter (together with some more lookups into `qmail-inject.c`)  one could draw the following possible causes for `qmail-inject` exiting with 111:

- out of memory
- invalid header fields(s) (either passed to `-f` or read from config/control files)
- unable to run `qmail-queue` (perhaps due to its non existance, or missing search path to it)
- being unable to `chdir` to `qmail`'s control/config file folder
- being unable to read qmail's config/control files

Checking the logs on your side might help also.

Comment: thanks your reply but the weird thing is that when i run this script manually it works. i checked the permissions, they seems well.

Comment: You might also make the script log the values for `$1` and `$2` to see what you are actually passing in. @YasarIslam

Comment: yes i did it and wrote them to a log file. all seems pretty nice. but still returns 111.@alk